# Random corrupt images

Tags: firefox, xubuntu

Ever since I switched over to xubuntu 13.04 when browsing the web random images will appear corrupt. I attempted everything from clearing firefox (cache, history, cookies etc) To a full blow re-install (I even double checked the md5). I run a dual boot on this machine and have no troubles with this in Windows, nor do any other computers on the network so it's not a connection issue. I also tested the HDD for bad sectors and ran a memory test both came up clear. I've never had this issue with any other distro previous (I've been using xubuntu since 8.04, and debian/redhat for longer)
The system has all the updates installed.
I've uploaded some screencaps of what it appears like [here](http://img837.imageshack.us/slideshow/webplayer.php?id=bur2.png)

Comment: I've seen something similar, but it's typically for flash embeds.  I would guess it's a video card trying to accelerated render a partially downloaded image and failing less than gracefully.  I'ld check for bugs on the video driver/card you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it had something to do with the video card. I checked around and came up with this.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1144558
I should be able to fix it from here, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: np...we just want stuff fixed.

Comment: Was it fixed? It says fix released.